# Updating large Dataset - Spring Transaction

Tags: oracle, spring

I am using Spring declarative transaction management. It commits the transaction only after execution of the method is completed. While updating a large data-set of more than twenty-thousand records in Oracle DB, I am getting an Exception

```
11:16:44,901 ERROR [STDERR] 
    Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: 
    Transaction TransactionImple < ac, 
    BasicAction: a0002ba:b7d:4f602e7f:80 
    status: ActionStatus.ABORTING > cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLING_BACK
11:16:44,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.checkTransactionActive(TxConnectionManager.java:332)
11:16:44,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.checkTransactionActive(BaseConnectionManager2.java:972)
11:16:44,901 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:161)
11:16:44,901 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 144 more
```

If I use plain JDBC to update such a large dataset using batch processing then I would lose the benefit of transaction (ACID) properties. But  I am facing issues while updating this large data-set with Spring transaction management.  Has anyone faced a similar issue or can suggest some alternative solution?

I am using JTATransactionManager and Jboss 5.1 and Spring + iBatis integration.

Comment: "If I use plain JDBC to update such a large dataset using batch processing then i would loose the benefit of transaction (ACID) properties"? Why?

Comment: What I mean was, it would be committed on every executeBatch stmt. I am using Spring transaction. If I use JDBC i would end up using autoComit=false.

Comment: @TarunSapra: What's wrong with that?

Comment: @TarunSapra: But autoCommit=false is exactly what you want if you want to have ACID transaction